# How to get count of eligible Endpoints of asegment in AWS Pinpoint through SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

We can get the eligible endpoints for a particular segment from the Pinpoint console, But the documentation for **AWS Pinpoint SDK** shows nothing about getting the count of **eligible Endpoint**  from a segemnt.
Is there any methods or API to get the count? Any work arounds are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No by now. There is no API for us to get the estimated acount.

You can refer the discussion for the same here.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=925614